# Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: windows, spring-boot, process, taskkill

I am trying to run a spring boot application by clicking on Run as -> Spring Boot App. I am getting the error as :

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

When I use netstat command, I see the below without process Ids:

```
netstat -na | find "8080"

TCP    0.0.0.0:8080   0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING

TCP    [::]:8080      [::]:0       LISTENING
```

Notice - I am running my code on **windows** machine

How do I kill these processes?

Comment: On windows machine add the `o` flag to get the process ID (as `netstat -nao | find "8080"`) and then you can kill it with `Taskkill`

Answer (score 9):

You can change your application's port number by providing something like `server.port=4567` in your `application.properties`.

OR

You can follow the steps as mentioned in http://www.codeman.in/blog/windows-kill-process-by-port-number-157 to kill process running on a port number:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the command lsof -i, it should list network connections among pid.
Or even better lsof -i :8080

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention I am running this code on my Windows machine. So, I am unable to run the above command lsof -i

Answer (score 0):

most likely "8080" is being used, either you end task/close the application or simply change the by default port which is being used by Spring boot. Multiple ways you can achieve, application.properties is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        } catch     (org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException e) {
//Runtime.exec("pkil")..
//or
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, otherargs);
//SpringApplication.run(Application.class, new String[]{"--server.port=8444"});
//when invoked recursively it is a port rebalancer for port usage among port pool with server as from client for startup stage via application restarts within many busy ports which are used before or without querying.

}
```